# ReferenceError: load is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to refresh the container on click event. For this task i create a function and call it in button attribute. But when i click on it then it giving me this error `ReferenceError: load is not defined`

### Button

```
<input type="button" value="Choose Container" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="sidebar-button" onclick="loadDiv();"/>
```

### Targeted Container

```
        <div class="modal-content custom-popup-personalize">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Container Slides</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body custom-personalize">
        <div id="slider" class="flexslider ">
        <ul class="slides loadOne">
        <?php      if(is_array($cookiProductsArray)){
        if($cookiProductsArray){
        foreach($cookiProductsArray as $cProduct){

        ?>
        <li>
        <img src="<?php echo $cProduct['popImage']; ?>"  />
        <div class="pop-prodcut-details">
        <h3><?php echo ucwords($cProduct['name']); ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $cProduct['description']; ?></p>


        </div>
        </li>

        <?php }
        }else{?>
        <span class="empty-container">Container is Empty!</span>
        <?php }

        }?>

        </ul>
        </div>

        </div>

        </div>
```

### Function

```
function loadDiv(){
    load(window.location + " .custom-popup-personalize");
}
```

Can any one please guide me where i'm wrong that i can resolve this issue.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef do you means this `$(".custom-popup-personalize").load();`

Comment: I meant any element you want to load the data in it .. read a docs here http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

Because the `load()` function is not defined in your script. If it is a custom function, you need to define it. If you are trying to use the jquery `load()` function, then you need to specify the container div for loading content in to it. Something like this:

```
$('#divId').load(url)
```

Comment: as per instruction i added this `$('#myModal').load(window.location + ".modal-dialog"); ` but this giving me another one error `NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/Project/personaliseyourflowers.modal-dialog`

Comment: the load() function is usually used to pull data from server. So you are aware of this?

Comment: No, so should i use it or not because i just want to reload the div

Comment: so you have contents for that div?

Comment: I  just want to refresh `custom-popup-personalize` div on click event, it has some static and dynamic data.

Comment: you cannot simply refresh a div. You need to use Ajax to get the dynamic data from server and write your own code to update the div contents.

Comment: Yes i'm already doing in same page its working properly ` `success:function(response){
         if(response) {
          $(".reloadCOnt").load(window.location + " .reloadCOnt");
         }
}` but with this div its not working